I use register.offset twice in a VBA function; the code is essentially identical. One works, the other results in a run-time error
This is extracted from my VBA function. Other than omitting irrelevant lines, I have not changed anything:
    With Selection
        areaCnt = .Areas.Count
        For i = 1 To areaCnt
            numRows = .Areas(i).Rows.Count + numRows
            numCols = .Areas(i).Columns.Count + numCols
        Next i
    End With

    With Worksheets("List What")
        Set defRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(numRows + 1, numCols + 1))
    End With

    order = ...
    With defRng
        Select Case order
            Case "Row"          ' copy rows
                For i = 1 To areaCnt
                    Set selArea = Selection.Areas(i)
                    Set selArea = selArea.Offset(1 - selArea.Rows(1).row, 0)     ' line 1
                    ...
                Next i
                ...
            Case "Column"       ' copy columns
                For i = 1 To areaCnt
                    Set selArea = Selection.Areas(i)
                    Set selArea = selArea.Offset(0, 1 - selArea.Columns(1).col)  ' line 2
                    ...
                Next i
                ...
        End Select
   End With

When called with "Row", the code (including line 1) works correctly. When called with "Column", the code (including line 2), results in the run-time error:
Run-time error '438':

Object doesn't support this property or method

I am mystified and frustrated. Any suggestions?

Change col to Column. There is no such property as col.
It is enough to write selArea.Row instead of selArea.Rows(1).row
and selArea.Column instead of selArea.Columns(1).Column.
